# Setting the left attribute of a binary tree node through a for loop

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a binary tree, being implemented through linked nodes (with: int element, BinaryNode left, BinaryNode  right, BinaryNode  parent attributes). And I want to set the the nth node from the root to, say, x. i.e. if n = 3, then I want to do root.left.left.left = x.

Initially, I was thinking of setting a temporary BinaryNode variable and doing the following:

```
BinaryNode temp = root;
BinaryNode x = new BinaryNode(10, null, null, null);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    temp = temp.left;
}
```

And then once I got to the end, I wanted to say, temp.left = x, but then I realized/thought that doing that wouldn't do anything to the actual tree, since temp is just a copy of the root?

So I how would I go about trying to do this? :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `temp` is not a copy of the root.  It is a *reference* to the root.  Therefore, your code would in fact modify the original tree.  However, you have another problem-- what if there aren't that many nodes in the tree?  In other words, if n is 5 and there are only three nodes in the `.left` chain of nodes, then you will end up getting a `NullPointerException`.  You need to be checking for null as you go down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
private void replace(BinaryNode node, int n, int x) {
    if (n==0) {
        node.x = x
        return;
    }
    if (node.left != null)
        replace(node.left, n-1, x);
}
```

And call it with `replace(root, 3, 10)` for instance

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same problem, though? Since node is a separate BinaryNode, and not part of the tree itself...